# Why does this bash script require me to press enter to continue?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, scripting

I was kindly helped a few minutes ago by a user named Juliano and the script works fine but it just baffles me why it continues to work when I press enter, if I don't it just sits there untill I have to keep pressing enter. I thought that was the job of the for loop?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    TIMEFORMAT=%6R
    for file in /home/test/videos/* ; do
     #for loop 2
     for (( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )); do
      #for loop 3
      for ext in avi mpg wmv mov; do
          base="${file##*/}"
          elapsed=$({ time ffmpeg -i "$file" -ar 44100 "${file%/*}/done/${base%.*}.$ext" &>/dev/null; } 2>&1)
          echo "$file $i $ext took $elapsed seconds"
        done
      done
    done
```

Also can I swap for loops 2 and 3?

Thanks all

### Update

How can I also make use of the variable "i" in the for loop so that it concatinates at the end of the file. Is this correct:

${file%/*}/done/${base%.*}**$i**.$ext

Thank you for anymore help.

Comment: Run your script with bash -x to see where it's pausing.

Comment: Also, `for x in *` is bad style. It will break if your files have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already answered in the other question. It was ffmpeg asking you to overwrite the output file. Giving unique names (with $i in the filename) and passing -y to ffmpeg solves the problem.

Comment: I made use of your exact new script with one location change and all it does not is just output but not actually execute the ffmpeg command?

Comment: It is hard to say the reason without more information. Run "bash -x script.sh" to see what bash is running. I fixed the script, again.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the `ffmpeg` program is what's waiting for the keypress at the end of the process. You might be able to send it a keypress, like:

```
echo -e \\n | time ffmpeg ...
```

which might echo a new line "into" the standard input of the ffmpeg program.

And yes, you can swap loop #2 and #3.

Comment: You are correct that has made it continue automatically - But do I have to replace the "time" with "echo -e \\n" as I need the time. Sorry for being a noob, but how do i get both. Thanks.

Comment: You can use both : `echo -e \\n | time ffmpeg ...`

Comment: Omg, sorry for being so retarded. Also how can I concatenate the variable "i" to the filename? Please see my update.